# NodeJs / Axios: timeout issues linked to high level of concurrency

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, promise, axios

I've set up a nodeJS server which basically receives an ad request, sends ad requests through Axios to multiple endpoints with a timeout (usually 1000 ms), and then parse and sends back all results.
On each pod around 600 requests per minute are performed to various external endpoints.
When we start the pod, requests run pretty well at the beginning, than after 1 or 2 minutes, all requests returns as timed out...

I use Promise.all to manage concurrency requests, you'll find below the adapterRequest component in charge of sending requests.
I also try to send some data within my cluster, I also get a timeout, which makes me confident on the fact that the issue is linked to Axios.

Getting into details, I create promise arrays thanks to the following module, than I use Promise.all to fetch data

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fakeServer = require('../test/fake-server');

let promiseCount = 0;

module.exports = (ssp, payload, endpoint, method, timeout) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  const cmd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? fakeServer : axios;
  const start = Date.now();
  const config = {
    ssp,
    url: endpoint,
    method,
    timeout,
    header: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Connexion: 'keep-alive',
    },
    data: payload,
  };
  cmd(config)
    .then((response) => {
      promiseCount += 1;
      console.log(ssp, 'RESPONSEOK', promiseCount);
      resolve({
        ssp,
        uri: config.url,
        requestbody: payload,
        requestheaders: config.header,
        responsebody: response.data,
        status: response.status,
        responsetimemillis: Date.now() - start,
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      promiseCount += 1;
      console.log(ssp, error.code, promiseCount);
      let responsebody;
      let status;
      if (error.response === undefined) {
        responsebody = undefined;
        status = undefined;
      } else {
        responsebody = error.response.data ? error.response.data : error.message;
        status = error.response.status;
      }
      resolve({
        ssp,
        uri: config.url,
        requestbody: payload,
        requestheaders: config.header,
        responsebody,
        status,
        responsetimemillis: Date.now() - start,
      });
    });
});
```

Should I try to use such modules as agentkeepalive, with one Axios instance per endpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think you should

Answer (score 0):

**Just for debugging**. before you try another module...

Inside axios config could you change header into headers and add KeepAlive like this

```
const http = require('http')
const https = require('https')
const config = {
ssp,
url: endpoint,
method,
timeout,
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  Accept: 'application/json',
},
data: payload,

  //keepAlive pools and reuses TCP connections, so it's faster
  httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
}
```